# How to close webdriver by different python script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, celery

I want to know is there a way to create a webdriver by script1.py , but close the webdriver by script2.py . I don't use the `time.sleep()` because I set these scripts to execute after few month. And I'm afraid that the scripts will delay due to the network crash. Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? You can create a driver instance in a class, put it in script0.py and then inherits two class in these files script1.py and script2.py.
But the question is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

The Python Selenium framework, [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), comes with a special `pytest` command-line option called, `--reuse-session`, which tells all your tests to reuse the same browser session, even if all the tests live in different Python files. (More info on [SeleniumBase command-line options here](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/customizing_test_runs.md).) When using `--reuse-session` mode, the first test run will spin up the web browser, and then the last test run will close it. This should give you what you're looking for, where a different Python script closes the browser than the one that originally opened it.